# Cocos2d V3 - Getting current sprite position?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, position, sprite, side-scroller

Probably quite a simple question! I'm making a side scrolling shooter game using Xcode5, with Cocos2d Version 3.

When the main character (on the left of the screen) flies up and down, I want the enemy (on the right of the screen) to follow him along the Y axis.

I've set up an action so the enemy enters, then moves to the main character's Y position. But the enemy moves to the main characters starting Y position, not it's current Y position.

Is there code to get the current position of a sprite? Or is there perhaps a better way to achieve this? Basically we want the enemy sprite to know the main characters Y position and move to it continuously.

Thanks

Comment: show some code ... otherwise any suggestion would be a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

Every CCNode has a position property.

```
@property(nonatomic,readwrite,assign) CGPoint position;
```

So use this:

```
CGPoint position = yourSprite.position;
```